# Blank web page in IE 11 and Chrome when creating html strings using jquery and json

Tags: jquery, html, json

When I try to load the following html into IE 11 or Chrome the web page is blank. I do not see any errors and when I debug it looks like the html is being created properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>  
<head>      
    <title>Strings</title>  
</head>  
<body>      
    <div id="strings"></div>      
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>      
    <script>  
       $.getJSON('GetStrings', function( data ) {
           var html = "";  
           for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
           html += '<b>' + data[i] + '</b></br>';              
           }              
           $('strings').html(html);          
       });      
    </script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: And what is it supposed to display? Where do you fetch data from? Where is JSON?

Comment: `$('#strings').html(html); ` add a `#` to your selector.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a wrong selector you have missed a `#` for id selector. But i think you should make a global function and call it when the dom is ready:

```
function getData() {
  $.getJSON('GetStrings', function(data) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      html += '<b>' + data[i] + '</b></br>';
    }
    $('#strings').html(html); // add a `#` to your selector
  });
}

$(function() { // doc ready block
  getData(); // call the getJson when document is ready
});
```